# Pygame allow scaling of window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am writing a game in Pygame and I want the user to be able to change the size of the window, while keeping it at the same aspect ratio.
[This is what happens when I try to resize it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2Lz9.png)

I have added this to my main loop

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((event.w, event.h), pygame.RESIZABLE)
```

But it has not done anything, or affected the program.

Is this possible, or will I have to add a settings menu with different sizes?

If possible, I would also like the fullscreen button to work, in this same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you have to change the parameters of pygame.display.set_mode() some what like this..

```
WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```